# Titanium Javascript: How to create dynamic eventListeners?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, titanium, addeventlistener

I have an array of buttons and I want to add an eventListener to each of them.

In the eventListener, I want to retrieve the width value of the button that is currently being pressed. How can I do that?

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
button[i].addEventListener(click, function(e) {
alert(/*How should I refer to THAT button*/)
})
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the event listener, you can use `this` to refer to the current button:

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert( this ); // <-- This inside the event listener = current button
    });
}
```

Another method is to wrap the loop's body in a closure, and create a local variable:

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    (function(button) { // <--- Local variable
        button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            alert( button );
        });
    })(button[i]);      // <-- Pass button
}
```

Instead of constructing a new function at each loop, you can also create a named function outside the loop:

```
function createButtonEvent(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert( button );
    });
}
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    createButtonEvent(button[i]);
}
```

Comment: which method would be most similar to the function format in Java, C++, Objective C, Perl, Phython?